# how to replace buttons with a row in datatable that can be clicked

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatables

hi expert need help i have button in every array like edit or delete
but what i want is i want to replace that buttons with a line that can be clicked in datatables

i have try using code below but just text inside the  can be click not the row in datatables

```
$row = array();
            $row[] = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="lihat_infostudent('."'".$infostudent->number."'".')"><tr><td><center>'."$no".'<center></td></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a `class` to the `tr` element on your code and the bind the `onclick` event to the defined class. See example below,

```
'<tr class="clickable_row" data-studentno="' . $infostudent->number . '"><td>....</td></tr>'
```

Then in your js file,

```
$('.clickable_row').on('click', function() {
    lihat_infostudent($(this).data('studentno'));
});
```

Finally in the css to give the pointer effect for the row,

```
tr.clickable_row {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: @WahyuArtadianto you can omit the css part, that css I used just to bring the mouse pointer effect on hover. Between, this css snippert is to styles you custom class defined